# What is this dark brown organism growing on a door frame?

Tags: species-identification, mycology

A few brown spots appeared on a door frame and within 1 week it has grown to this size (~15cm). I have no idea what it is. How do I remove it completely? I worry that if I just wipe it off, it will just regrow from within the door frame. I've attached 2 pictures to assist with the identification.

Edit: I poked it with a stick and tiny white insects (~2mm) came crawling out of the structure.

My location: South India

[image: Picture 1]
[image: Picture 2]

Answer (score 1):

Termites.

Photograph the insects and we will try to identify further. If the insects keep running, freeze some. This could be a big problem, so get good information soon.

Online I see this article that might help.

" An identification guide to the wood destroying termites of south India"

Journal of the Indian Academy of Wood Science
ISSN 0972-172X Volume 8 Number 2
J Indian Acad Wood Sci (2011) 8:148-151
DOI 10.1007/s13196-012-0028-9

Comment: Can termites be this small(~2mm) though? Unfortunately I can't get any more pictures because this is in my relative's house and I was just staying there for a while. I'll ask them to further look into this. Thanks :)

Comment: Ask them to trace the tunnel down to the nest, if they can.

Comment: @trinitrotoluene - if your relatives haven't got it resolved already, by the time termites are coming through the outside of wood, the internal is already overflowing with them and their tunnels. It is highly likely that they have a heavy infestation and will need an exterminator to get rid of them fully, then some serious repair work to trace, remove and replace the damaged wood.